# how to include ' in search term

Tags: php

I have a search field where users can input a search term. I have some words with a ' in them and if entered, the search results do not pick them up. I am using PDO/prepared statements.

Is there a way to safely include ' in the search?

I think the problem is coming in here, the data I am passing from the controller ie: the filter_var function

```
$searchtext = filter_var($_GET['searchtext'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I tried using `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` but now the search doesn't work at all.

Comment: Please give an example of the the text you're entering that's causing the error, and the code you used to add the flag, and the result you're seeing. If I use `filter_var($text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, ['flags' => FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES]);`, which is what I assume you're doing, it looks ok to me.

Comment: Sanitising means "look at the data and then remove anything nasty from it".  When you are using PDO, the DB compiles the query first, and then adds the data, so the input data can never form part of the query, thus preventing [mitigating] injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're corrupting input with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`:

```
var_dump(filter_var("O'Brian", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

```
string(11) "O&#39;Brian"
```

Get rid of it, you don't need it at all if you're using prepared statements correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am using PDO and prepared statements so that should be fine, but I am always over cautious, haha